# Calculating a simpler derivative for $\frac{1+\cot x}{2- \sec x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm fairly new to derivative exercises, and I am often concerned about the fact that many of my answers are larger than the original function. For example:

$$\frac{1+\cot x}{2- \sec x}$$

Becomes

$$\frac{-\csc^2x \cdot(2-\sec x) + \sec x \cdot \tan x \cdot (1 + \cot x)}{(2-\sec x)^2}$$

I am assuming that this is technically the right answer, but it is surprisingly long and would probably make things very messy if I try to calculate the second derivative.

So my question is, is there a way to simplify this derivate in case I need to calculate yet another derivative? I'm afraid they just keep getting larger.

Comment: Try to rewrite everything as quotients of sine and cosine and see what can be simplified

Comment: It is sort of unreasonable to expect derivatives to be simpler than the original.  In general they may very well get messier and messier...  When I see what you posted, I think "it could've been much worse" and I consider myself lucky that it's only that "bad."

Answer (score 1):

we got this here
$$-\frac{\csc ^2(x) (-3 \sin (x)+\sin (3 x)-5 \cos (x)+4 \cos (2 x)+\cos (3
   x)+4)}{4 (1-2 \cos (x))^2}$$
i have found this tonight
$$-{\frac { \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}+ \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( x \right) +2\, \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-2\,\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( 
x \right) }{ \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( 4\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,\cos \left( x \right) +
1 \right) }}
$$

Comment: This doesn't look simpler to me... (what the OP asked for).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a clearly "simpler" answer. Wolfram Alpha gives the following format, but it is really up to your taste which one to choose...

$\frac{\tan(x)(\cot(x) + 1) \sec(x)}{(2-\sec(x))^2} - \frac{\csc^2(x)}{2 - \sec(x)}$